# Checked Radio Button

Tags: html, jsp

Am trying to make a HTML page that calculate the BMI for adults and children

i want from user to choose the type of calculation if it for adult or children

using radio button but I do not want it to open a new page .. if user check any button

i want it when he check e.x. the Adult radio button the input text field appears under the two radio buttons .. if i change my mind then check the Children radio button ... another input text field appears Instead of those for adult one

i don't know if my request is clear or no .. i hope so

i wish some one help me how to make that

actually I could not search about it in Google cause i don't know what i suppose to write there ... very beginner :D

so if the answer is a link to read about that .. i 'll accept that ^_^

Regards

Comment: Learn about JavaScript and the DOM. w3schools offers decent tutorials.

Comment: @JBNizet: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) it will not exactly solve your problem but will give you idea how to do it .

Answer (score 2):

you could do this with jQuery.
You should hide both input fields, and if the users checks a radiobutton fade the corresponding input in.

```
<div id="formdiv">
    <form>
        <label for="1">Radio 1</label><input type="radio" id="1" name="choose" />
        <label for="2">Radio 2</label><input type="radio" id="2" name="choose" />
        <input type="text" class="1" name="input1" />
        <input type="text" class="2" name="input2" />
    </form>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='choose']").change(function() {
        var inputToFadeIn = $(this).attr('id');
        $("input[type='text']:visible").animate({visibility: 'hidden'}, 500);
        $('.' + inputToFadeIn).animate({visibility: 'visible'}, 500);
    });​
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    ​input[type='text']
    {
        visibility:hidden;
    }​​
</style>
```

Have now tested it on JSFiddle, but doesn't work. Could someone explain http://jsfiddle.net/7eKP6/?

Comment: ` You should hide both input field `

OK i really want to make that but how ??

Comment: @Mahmoud See edit. It behaves strange YET, but asked for explanation, as I can't tell why either.

Comment: @Mahmoud already understand why it behaved strange, but now my solution behaves strange too, or better, it doesn't even behave because nothing happens.